# java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

Im running Eclipse Juno on Mac OSX 10.8.4, I tried to update my jdk to 1.7 when I run my Java App and I have this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle
```

if I run on terminal

```
java -version
```

I get this

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

for updating this I set on Eclipse

Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs - Duplicate

```
JRE home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
JRE name: Java SE 7 (MacOS X Default)
```

also changed compiler level

```
Window - Preferences - Java - Compiler - Compiler compilance level: 1.7
```

also added next lines to /Users/myUser/.bash_profile:

```
VA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

export JAVA_HOME=$VA_HOME
export CLASSPATH=$VA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

but still getting same error

Any help I'll appreciate

Comment: I'm not sure if it is different for mac installs, but on windows, you don't need '/Contents/Home' in the 'JRE home' property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your launch configuration, check that the right JRE System Library is on the Classpath

Comment: I got it!!! when I set up my JRE I clicked on duplicate my 1.6 and only changed the JRE Home and JRE Name but I had to click on ADD, not DUPLICATE because JRE System Libraries were still referencing to JRE 1.6 libraries thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added JAVA_HOME to your PATH? Usually you get this problem due to a bad installation of the SDK. Try

```
javac -version
```

From the command line and see if this differs to

```
java -version
```

And produces the same NoClassDefFoundError as above.

Comment: javac -version:   
javac 1.7.0_40

java -version:   
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)       I think it is the same version on both

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason of `java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError` is that you have a jar in your classpath which references another jar which is missing in classpath. The referencing classes won't be initialized.

Now for your case, you upgraded to 1.7 which would have added dependencies. Make sure your classpath now refers to jdk/jre 1.7

Comment: I also added this line to my .bash_profile: VA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

export JAVA_HOME=$VA_HOME
export CLASSPATH=$VA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

the formatted code is on my updated question but still getting same result